How to Display Currency Values with Thousand Separators in a Material-UI DataGrid
I am building a React application using Material-UI's DataGrid component. I need to display two columns, allowed_amount and outstanding_amount, formatted as USD currency with a dollar sign ($) and thousand separators. Additionally, I want the headers of all columns to be bold. I tried looking into the documentation but had no success. Please help!
    // defining columns
    const data_cols = [
        { field: 'cert_id', headerName: 'ID', width: 130 },
        { field: 'cert_name', headerName: 'Certificate Name', width: 180 },
        { field: 'outstanding_amount', headerName: 'Outstanding Amount', width: 150, type: 'number'},
        { field: 'allowed_amount', headerName: 'Allowed Amount', width: 150, type: 'number' },
        { field: 'broker_city', headerName: 'Broker City', width: 150 },
        { field: 'broker_state', headerName: 'Broker State', width: 150 },
        { field: 'broker_country', headerName: 'Broker Country', width: 150 },
        { field: 'broker_zip', headerName: 'Broker Zip', width: 150 }
    ];

    return(
        <Box
        sx = {{
            width: '70%',
            margin: 'auto',
            backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
            boxShadow: 3,
            borderRadius: 2,
            padding: 2,
            marginTop: 5,
            height: 420,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column'
        }}
        >
        <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: '4px' }}>
            <DataGrid
                rows={rows}
                columns={data_cols}
                initialState={{
                    pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 5 } }
                  }}
                pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
                loading={loading}
                autoHeight={false}
                disableSelectionOnClick
                getRowId={(row) => row.cert_id}
            />
        </div>
        </Box>
    )


// Import necessary libraries
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

// Define columns with formatting and bold headers
const data_cols = [
    { field: 'cert_id', headerName: 'ID', width: 130, headerClassName: 'bold-header' },
    { field: 'cert_name', headerName: 'Certificate Name', width: 180, headerClassName: 'bold-header' },
    { 
        field: 'outstanding_amount', 
        headerName: 'Outstanding Amount', 
        width: 150, 
        type: 'number',
        headerClassName: 'bold-header',
        valueFormatter: (params) => {
            return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'USD',
                minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            }).format(params.value);
        }
    },
    { 
        field: 'allowed_amount', 
        headerName: 'Allowed Amount', 
        width: 150, 
        type: 'number', 
        headerClassName: 'bold-header',
        valueFormatter: (params) => {
            return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'USD',
                minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            }).format(params.value);
        }
    },
    { field: 'broker_city', headerName: 'Broker City', width: 150, headerClassName: 'bold-header' },
    { field: 'broker_state', headerName: 'Broker State', width: 150, headerClassName: 'bold-header' },
    { field: 'broker_country', headerName: 'Broker Country', width: 150, headerClassName: 'bold-header' },
    { field: 'broker_zip', headerName: 'Broker Zip', width: 150, headerClassName: 'bold-header' }
];

format the allowed_amount and outstanding_amount columns as USD currency with a dollar sign ($) and thousand separators in Material-UI's DataGrid component, you can use the valueFormatter property in the column definitions. Additionally, you can make all column headers bold using the headerClassName property.
